# multiple ubuntu kernels and nvdia driver question

Tags: boot, nvidia

-- perhaps this is a basic question, I have 2 kernels now installed on my ubuntu 20.04.4, I know I can boot from either one, and can set default kernel in grub, my question is now I am using one older kernel, the nvidia works fine, if I boot from newer kernel there is no nvidia driver installed, if I do a remove nvidia command, does this effect the if I boot from older kernel version ? and can I install the nvidia driver again for the new kernel?
or I have to remove the one installed first then install for this kernel ? \

thanks.

Comment: It depends. Old Nvidia drivers do not work with new kernels. There is no way to answer this, and you've not provided the versions of either the driver or the kernel.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the two kernels are 5.13.0-30, 5.16.11, nvidia driver is 510

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvidia graphics drivers are generally robust in terms of compatibility with upgrades of other packages which are installed in Ubuntu, so it is safe to try booting Ubuntu from either of the two kernels which you have installed. Conversely there is no harm done by removing the installed Nvidia proprietary graphics driver because Ubuntu has an open source Nouveau graphics driver installed by default for computers that have an Nvidia GPU but do not have an Nvidia proprietary graphics driver installed. The Nouveau graphics driver is your Ubuntu's failsafe graphics driver, so you should not uninstall it whatever else you do.

Comment: thanks for the reply